# Capturando clique em uma área específica do Google Maps (GMaps API)

Tags: google-maps

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo web que faz uso da API do Google Maps para mapear talhões de fazendas, e os destacar com cores diferentes de acordo com o nível de uma determinada praga.

Eu preciso capturar o clique do usuário dentro da área selecionada como mostra a imagem abaixo, encontrei alguns algorítmos capazes de calcular o local do clique mas estou com dúvidas para aplicá-lo. Estou utilizando JavaScript.

Quanto for feito o clique dentro da área, eu quero fazer uma determinada ação, a minha dúvida é: como capturar este clique, usando a API do Google Maps, dentro de uma área específica mapeada por latitude e longitude?

[image: A imagem mostra o mapeamento por pontos de coordenada feito usando google Earth]

Algorítmo que encontrei para calcular o ponto dentro da área:

```js
window.isPointInPolygon = function(pontoClique, arrayCoordenadas) {
  var intersectCount = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < arrayCoordenadas.size() - 1; j++) {
    if (rayCastIntersect(pontoClique, arrayCoordenadas.get(j), arrayCoordenadas.get(j + 1))) {
        intersectCount++;
    }
  }
  return ((intersectCount % 2) == 1); // odd = inside, even = outside;
}

var rayCastIntersect = function(pontoClique, LatLngVertA, LatLngVertB) {
  var aY = LatLngVertA.lat;
  var bY = LatLngVertB.lat;
  var aX = LatLngVertA.lng;
  var bX = LatLngVertB.lng;
  var pY = pontoClique.lat;
  var pX = pontoClique.lng;

  if ((aY > pY && bY > pY) || (aY < pY && bY < pY) || (aX < pX && bX < pX)) {
    return false; // a and b can't both be above or below pt.y, and a or
    // b must be east of pt.x
  }

  var m = (aY - bY) / (aX - bX); // Rise over run
  var bee = (-aX) * m + aY; // y = mx + b
  var x = (pY - bee) / m; // algebra is neat!
  return x > pX;
  }
```

Obs: O Algorítmo estava em Java, eu o adaptei para JavaScript que é o que eu preciso.

Atenciosamente;

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu registro um evento `addListener('click', function);` no talhão, a API do GMaps trata de verificar se o click foi feito na área destacada.
([veja addListener aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=pt-br))

```js
var area = new google.maps.Polygon(area_opts);
area.setMap(map);
//(...)
area.addListener('click', doSomething);

function doSomething(){
console.log('Você clicou no talhão');
}
```